# Asp.net and ext.net library: How to fire an event on key return?

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

i'm using Asp.net with Ext.net component. I would like to know if it is possible to fire an event when the user press the enter key into a text box. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found by myself: starting from asp.net 2.0, panel and forms control has **DefaultButton** that accept control name of a button.